# Python Flask app throwing RuntimeError: working outside of request context

Tags: python, flask

Hi guys Im new to Python im trying to construct a decorator for a simple flask application. I keep getting a RuntimeError: working outside of request context. Here is the full stacktrace, dont know what Ive done wrong here probably a noob error

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, session
from flask import session
from functools import wraps

app = Flask(__name__)

def check_login(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'logged_in' in session:
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return 'You are NOT logged in. Please log in to continue'
    return decorated_function()

@app.route('/')
def default_route():
    return 'This is the default page.'

@app.route('/page1')
@check_login
def page_one():
    return 'This is page1.'

app.secret_key = 'Youwillneverguess'

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

As I said I'm new to python any help you guys can give me would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `return decorated_function()` should be `return decorated_function` (note the lack of trailing parenthesis in the second example) - you're *invoking* the `decorated_function` rather than returning it.

Comment: @Sean Vieira Why don't you post that as a solotion?

Comment: Thank you very much, I was looking at this for 2 hours today! saved some of my hair

Answer (score 1):

```
return decorated_function()
```

should be

```
return decorated_function
```

Note the lack of trailing parenthesis in the second example. In the first example, you're invoking the `decorated_function` rather than returning it.